# load selenium chrome instance in a python widget

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

there´s any python component
to do someting like this(this is java)

https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013135-jxbrowser-selenium

i use python tkinter to open chrome instances on a click button,
i'd like to run selenium chrome instance in a python widget on a click button,
at the top of python gui app a button and when you click on it open the selenium chrome instance  in a  tkinter frame
is it possible to do something like that with a python GUI

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, I would try something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

#Your paths and driver might be different.
CHROME_PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' 
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = 'chromedriver.exe'
WINDOW_SIZE = "1920,1080"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") # This is optional, but faster than gui
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
chrome_options.binary_location = CHROME_PATH

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)

url = "https://www.example.com" # Your url goes here.
browser.get(url)
# - You'll need to copy the button's xpath and place it in here.
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'copy_xpath_into_here'))) 

# click on button - You'll need to copy the button's xpath and place it in here, too.
selectElem=browser.find_element_by_xpath('copy_xpath_into_here').click()
```

Comment: how does this answer the question?